# Does Flot supports interval bar plot?

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

Does [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) offers an option to make the bar chart float?. I am looking for a Flot equivalent to [interval bar plot](http://home.gna.org/pychart/doc/module-interval-bar-plot.html) (PyChart). The following picture is taken from the link:

[image]

(I am aware that Flot may not support this since it seems like each bar in Flot only has one variable, but I am not sure).

Edit: Any javascript library suggestion is also welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed a workaround using Flot's bar chart and Flot's [stacking](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/stacking/). Basically for the empty space, I create a stack with white color (which somehow got translated into transparent except for the edges). Unfortunately, Flot's stacking require all stacks of the same level to be of the same type/color. In order to circumvere this, some of the bars have zero width in the stacks of wrong colors. Result looks surprisingly good!

[image]

The corresponding code follows (the example data does NOT corresponds to the image above, since it would be a little too large. This shows only two of the "colors").

```
var series = [
    {
      data: [
          [24.0, 0],            
          [6.93333333333, 1],
          [6.95, 2],
          [6.91666666667, 3],
          [6.95, 4],            
      ],
      color: "#FFFFFF",
    },
    {
      data: [
          [0.0, 0],
          [0.0666666666667, 1],
          [0.05, 2],
          [0.0833333333333, 3],
          [0.05, 4],            
      ],
      color: "#FFFF00",
    },
];
date_ticks_pre = [[0, "Okt 19, 2014"], [1, "Okt 20, 2014"], [2, "Okt 21, 2014"], [3, "Okt 22, 2014"], [4, "Okt 23, 2014"]];
var options = {
  series: {
    bars: {
      show: true,
      barWidth: .75,
      horizontal: true,
      align: "center"
    },
    stack: true,
  },
  xaxis: {
    ticks: 24,
  },
  yaxis: {
    ticks: date_ticks_pre,
  },
  zoom: { interactive: true },
  pan: { interactive: true },
};
$.plot('#flot_plot',
       series,
       options);
```